# Vibrating point cloud in rviz

Tags: ros-melodic, pcl, ubuntu, translation, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

So as you can see on the code I'm creating two subscribing nodes:

1. Subscribing from **laser scanner**
2. Subscribing  **/tf** which is result of transformation **/odom -> /robot**

In this code I'm using `tf2_sensor_msgs` to transform `point_cloud` (which is just /mybot/laser/scan transformed into point_cloud) with `do_transform_cloud()`using `/tf`  and publish it to topic `/laserPointCloud`.

My problem is that when I'm publishing it to RVIZ i can see some kind of **vibrations** of the subscribed `point_cloud`. I was thinking that it may be because frequency of publishing `/mybot/laser/scan` is **40Hz** and of the `/tf` **30** but I've made two separate scripts to publish pointcloud at 30Hz (to be the same as /tf using `rate.sleep()`) and **it didn't help** (the vibrations appeared like in the given code).

Ubuntu:18.04 LTS / ROS: Melodic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338112/vibrating-point-cloud-in-rviz./) by [asbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/49167/asbird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh, well that's your problem. You shouldn't be subscribing to the '/tf' topic directly. You should be using alistener and a buffer so that the library does all the math for you.

http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29

Then use the 'transform' method from the BufferInterface http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/tf2_ros/html/python/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2